# How do I use static libraries in Objective-C (OS X)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm a beginner programmer using Xcode, and I'm trying to make a static library so that I don't have to copy files over every time I write a new program.  Problem is, I could not find a satisfactory explanation of how to do this -- I've tried a few tutorials and I'm sure I've skipped some steps.  So:

I have an Xcode project with my class files.  It's got a class to deal with large numbers called Large -- `Large.h` and `Large.m`.  I chose to make it a static library, and I built it.

Then, I made a new project and followed [this](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html).  I tried to `#import "Large.h"`, but Xcode still wouldn't recognize the class `Large` as it does in my projects that have a copy of the source files themselves.  I'm probably doing a ton of things wrong...  What do I do?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you done a search here on SO? The "Related" sidebar (below right) turns up a whole bunch of questions that look useful; similar questions also would've come up in the drop-down menu when you were creating this question. Did you look at those?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tutorial some times ago... Hope this will help you:

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/xcode-static-libraries/